Nx generators with advanced Schematics templates in file name
I'm trying to get my NX generator to generate some files with the generateFiles function. I have a template file for which I want to dynamically assign part of their name. File name __name@dasherize__-details.component.ts.template. Inside of it I have some code which is also dynamically assigned eg. <%= dasherize(name) %>-details.component.html.
According to docs this is the way to do substitutions and even for functions in the file but nothing for functions inside file name.
After running
nx g components --name GeneratorTesting --project ui-project

I get the following result:
CREATE libs/my-app/ui-project/ui/src/lib/generator-testings/__name@dasherize__-details/__name@dasherize__-details.component.ts

Inside the file (strings.)dasherize function is executed as expected (I get generator-testing-details.component.html), but for the file name I can't get it to work. I am updating the generators as the project went up a couple of major angular and nx versions so I know for a fact this used to work.
What am I missing?
I am on @nx/devkit v19.8.2
I have tried looking at docs and searching for similar problem but can't seem to find it. I also tried using same syntax as in file itself __dasherize(name)__ , but got same results If nothing else will help I will pass additional substitions to generateFiles(tree, absoluteTemplatePath, targetPath, substitutions);, but that is my last resort as I want to make as few changes to templates as possible and keep everything as simple as possible.
